# What's the idiomatic way to copy from a primitive type reference by value?

Tags: rust

Consider the following snippet:

```
fn example(current_items: Vec<usize>, mut all_items: Vec<i32>) {
    for i in current_items.iter() {
        let mut result = all_items.get_mut(i);
    }
}
```

The compiler is complaining about `i` being `&mut usize` instead of `usize`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&usize: std::slice::SliceIndex<[()]>` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:3:36
  |
3 |         let mut result = all_items.get_mut(i);
  |                                    ^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[()]>` is not implemented for `&usize`
```

I've dug through the docs but the only way I see to satisfy the compiler is `i.clone()`.

I'm definitely missing something obvious here. What's the idiomatic way to copy from primitive type reference by value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`iter()` on `Vec<T>` returns an iterator implementing `Iterator<&T>`, that is, this iterator will yield references into the vector. This is the most general behavior which allows convenient usage with non-copyable types.

However, primitive types (actually, any types which implement `Copy` trait) will be copied upon dereference anyway, so you just need this:

```
for i in current_items.iter() {
    let mut result = all_items.get_mut(*i);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use reference destructuring pattern:

```
for &i in current_items.iter() {
    let mut result = all_items.get_mut(i);
}
```

Now `i` is `usize` automatically and you don't need to dereference it manually.

Comment: Now, I swear I did that following all the docs I've read before, and compiler was complaining about unable to dereference `i` and now it compiles... well I must've missed something. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

> What's the idiomatic way to copy from primitive type reference by value?

You need to use `*` to dereference a reference.

```
let my_usize: usize = 5;
let ref_to_my_usize: &usize = &my_usize;
let copy_of_my_usize: usize = *ref_to_my_usize;
```

You can also dereference directly in your loop:

```
for &x in myvec.iter() {
//  ^-- note the &
}
```

Comment: Though somehow it didn't compile before (hence this question), but I did learn something new regarding the `&x` destructuring. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `iter` if you need an `&mut` reference. Use [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut) instead.

Comment: I do apologize for my terrible snippet. In this case `current_items` contains the indices to items in `all_items`, so I'm using immutable reference (&uint) to access a mutable reference.