# What is an idiomatic way to collect an iterator of &T into a collection of Ts?

Tags: reference, rust, iterator

I need to collect an iterator over a slice of `&str`s into a collection of `&str`s. The problem is that the iterator yields `&&str`s.

I tried to map from `&word` to `word`, and while it works, I don't know if it is considered good or if there are better options available.

The problem:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let words = &["hello", "world", "I'm", "a", "Rustacean!"];
    let hashset = words.iter().collect::<HashSet<&str>>();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=98bc4232ec9129ab13654330c4a0be37)

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::collections::HashSet<&str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&&str`
 --> src/main.rs:5:32
  |
5 |     let hashset = words.iter().collect::<HashSet<&str>>();
  |                                ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::collections::HashSet<&str>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&&str>`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&&str>` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashSet<&str>`
```

My solution:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let words = &["hello", "world", "I'm", "a", "Rustacean!"];
    let hashset = words.iter().map(|&w| w).collect::<HashSet<&str>>();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ca8e920da6b06e48e4c9e7b280b90056)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `T` implements `Copy` then you can use [`Iterator::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied). Otherwise, if it implements `Clone` then you can use [`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned). Like any immutable reference, `&str` implements both `Clone` and  `Copy`, so you can use `copied`:

```
let hashset: HashSet<&str> = words.iter().copied().collect();
```

Answer (score 18):

Is a bicycle an idiomatic way to get from one city to another? Like most things in software (and life), it **depends**.

## If your type implements `Copy`

I'd prefer these in this order:

1. `some_iter.copied()`
2. `some_iter.cloned()`
3. `some_iter.map(|&v| v)`
4. `some_iter.map(|v| *v)`
5. `some_iter.map(Clone::clone)`
6. `some_iter.map(|v| v.clone())`

## If your type implements `Clone`

I'd prefer these in this order:

1. `some_iter.cloned()`
2. `some_iter.map(Clone::clone)`
3. `some_iter.map(|v| v.clone())`

## If your type doesn't implement `Copy` or `Clone`

Then you cannot trivially create an owned value. The type may implement [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) or there may be a bespoke function or method that you can call inside of `map`, or you may simply not be able to do anything.

---

In your case, I'd use `words.iter().copied().collect::<HashSet<_>>()`.

See also:

- [Iterating over a slice's values instead of references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40613725/155423)
- [What's the idiomatic way to copy from a primitive type reference by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25684227/155423)
- [Why is "&&" being used in closure arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43828013/155423)
- [Why does the argument for the find closure need two ampersands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33971087/155423)